# Optimizing Frobenius norm in R

Tags: r, multivariate-regression

Suppose that $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$. Is there a function in R that gives the optimal solution $\hat{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times p}$, which minimizes $\Vert Y-XB \Vert_F^2 $? (I cannot compute inverses, since it is nearly impossible to invert $X^TX$)

Comment: I think you need to explain why you can't compute inverses. Inverses aren't needed, but it matters whether the problem is that $X^TX$ is (nearly) singular or that it's too large or something else.

Comment: One such `R` function is `lm`.